# Will AWS Lambda implement Java 17

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Java 17 will be release next month. As it is a Long Term Support release (LTS), does anyone know if AWS Lambda will propose it as a Runtime in addition to other Java LTS (Java 8 and 11) ?

Comment: I would expect so.  But the only people who know for sure will be the Amazon folks who are (or will be) doing the work and their management.  (But if past history is anything to go by, you may have to wait some time after the Java 17 LTS release ...)

Comment: Java 17 is out for several weeks. I contacted AWS via my corporate AWS Support. They are not able to give an estimated date for Java 17 implementation in AWS Lambda ...

Comment: It's not quite the same as a runtime, but I manage a set of publicly-available custom AWS Lambda base images for Java 17, 18, and 19 published at https://gallery.ecr.aws/aleph0io/lambda/java and https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/aleph0io/aws-lambda-java. They work great for AWS Lambda functions packaged as Docker images. Source code available at https://github.com/aleph0io/aws-lambda-java-base-images for the curious.

Comment: AWS [confirmed](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/issues/29#issuecomment-1172143440) they are working on it:

> Java 17 support for Lambda is included in our roadmap planning, however due to some uncertain dependencies we don't yet have a timeline that's ready to share.